# Applying Patch to Asp.Net MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, patch

Creating a patch utility that will update my current website with my patch. when user login to its system and there is an update available it will prompt to user and if user accept it it will update its system. I want to know when this process starts i want the website to stop fulfilling request from other users until the files are copied so there is no malfunctioning occurs. **I want to know what will be the best approach to take the website down although user is logged in to the same website** and many other will try to access it? Im using Asp.Net MVC 2. I hope that my question is clear to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built in method to take an asp.net application offline. Here is a link describing what to do

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/061207.htm

Hope the gets you started.

Bob